# ZF2 - How do I pass constructor arguments to a Service in Module.php

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have a PHP class that has a constructor which takes arguments:

ex:

Users.php

```
namespace Forms;
class Users
{
  protected $userName;
  protected $userProperties = array();

  public function __construct($userName, array $userProperties = null) 
  {
     $this->userName = $userName;
     $this->userProperties = $userProperties;
  }
  public function sayHello()
  {
    return 'Hello '.$this->userName;
  }
}
```

Now, I am trying to use this class in a Model file like this:

```
$form = new Forms\Users( 'frmUserForm', array(
            'method' => 'post',
            'action' => '/dosomething',
            'tableWidth' => '800px'
            ) );
```

It works just fine. However, in order to write Unit tests, I need to refactor this to a Service Factory, so I can mock it.

So, my Service factory now looks like this:

```
public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'initializers' => array(
                function ($instance, $sm)
                {
                    if ( $instance instanceof ConfigAwareInterface )
                    {
                        $config = $sm->get( 'Config' );
                        $instance->setConfig( $config[ 'appsettings' ] );
                    }
                }
            ),
            'factories' => array(
                'Forms\Users' => function ($sm )
                {
                    $users = new \Forms\Users();
                    return $users;
                },
            )
        );
    }
```

With this refactoring in place, I have two questions:

1. How do I use the Forms\Users Service in the Model File, considering ServiceLocator is not available in a model file?
2. How can I change the Service Factory instance to take arguments for the constructor while instantiating Users class in the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced similar issue some time. Then I decide not to pass arguments to Factory itself. But build setter methods for handling this like.

```
namespace Forms;
class Users
{
  protected $userName;
  protected $userProperties = array();

  public function setUserName($userName) 
  {
      $this->userName = $userName;
  }
  public function setUserProperties($userProperties) 
  {
      $this->userProperties = $userProperties;
  }         
  public function sayHello()
  {
      return 'Hello '.$this->userName;
  }
}
```

You can implement your model ServiceLocatorAwareInterface interface Then it would can call any service like below.

```
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class MyModel implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface
{
    protected $service_manager;
    public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $this->service_manager = $serviceLocator;
    }

    public function getServiceLocator()
    {
        return $this->service_manager;
    }

    public function doTask($name, $properties)
    {
        $obj =  $this->getServiceLocator('Forms\Users');
        $obj->setUserName($name);
        $obj->setUserProperties($properties);
    }
}
```